# MenuItem with image as header ignores alignment

Tags: wpf, xaml

First of all, I know there are lot of questions about alignment in wpf, and I've read some of them, but none seems to work in this case...

### What do I have

I've a menu, where the third `MenuItem` doesn't have a text but an image. To be exact, this one:

[image: What I have]

I want this element to be ***right aligned***, so after looking at some examples and problem with alignment questions in SO, I'm using the following code:

```
<MenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
  <MenuItem.Header>
    <StackPanel>
      <Image Source="Resources/Img/donarBoton.gif" UseLayoutRounding="False" />
    </StackPanel>
  </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

### Problem

As you can see, even whith the **HorizontalAlignment** set to *right*, it doesn't appear on the right side.

I've read about it and found that the `Menu` where it is, need to have the same property set to **Stretch**, what I've tried too with no success. I even tried it with the `DockPanel` where the menu is located (just to try, I'm not used to WPF yet), but it does nothing either.

I've tried to add a text element after my image element too, in order to see if the problem is the `MenuItem` or any other thing in my configuration, but it didn't move to the right side either.

What am I doing wrong?

There's the full `DockPanel` code:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="superiorDock" Height="25" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="307">
  <Menu x:Name="superiorMenu" Width="307"  Height="25" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_1}">
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_2}"/>
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_3}"/>
      <Separator/>
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_4}"/>
      <Separator/>
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_5}"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_6}">
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_7}"/>
      <Separator/>
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_8}"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
      <MenuItem.Header>
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="Resources/Img/donarBoton.gif" UseLayoutRounding="False" />
        </StackPanel>
      </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

***Thanks in advance***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="superiorDock" Height="25" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="307">
  <Menu x:Name="superiorMenu" Width="307"  Height="25" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_1}">
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_2}"/>
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_3}"/>
      <Separator/>
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_4}"/>
      <Separator/>
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_5}"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_6}">
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_7}"/>
      <Separator/>
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@topMenu_8}"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
      <MenuItem.Header>
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="Resources/Img/donarBoton.gif" UseLayoutRounding="False" />
        </StackPanel>
      </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

The default `ItemsPanel` of the `Menu` uses a [`WrapPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel(v=vs.110).aspx). The panel defined in the `ItemsPanel` will be used as the container of the `MenuItem`s.
`WrapPanel` doesn't respect the `HorizontalAlignment` property of its children. That's why we change the `ItemsPanel` to one that does support this: `DockPanel`.

Comment: It worked, applying this Template to the Items in the panel. Could you edit with a bit of explanation about it? Thanks!

Comment: Added some explanation.